# An asymptotic formula involving the $2$-torsion subgroup of the class group of real quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms

Let $R$ be an order in some number field $K$ (not necessarily maximal). Then the class number $\text{Cl}(R)$ is equal to the cardinality of the Picard group of $R$, which is the group of equivalence classes of invertible fractional ideals of $R$. There is a unique quadratic order $R_D$ for each discriminant $D > 0$, and we put $h(D)$ for the class number of $R_D$. It is well-known from Gauss that $h(D)$ is also the number of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence classes of binary quadratic forms with integer coefficients of discriminant $D$. Let $\epsilon_D = u + v \sqrt{D}$, where $(u,v)$ is the smallest positive pair which solves the equation

$$\displaystyle u^2 - Dv^2 = \pm 4.$$

Moreover, it is a famous theorem of Siegel that the asymptotic formula

$$\displaystyle \sum_{D < x} h(D) \log \epsilon_D = \frac{\pi^2}{36} x^{3/2} + O(x).$$

Let $h_2(D)$ denote the size of the 2-torsion subgroup of $\text{Cl}(R_D)$.  Is there an analogous asymptotic formula for

$$\displaystyle \sum_{D < x} h_2(D) \log \epsilon_D ?$$

Comment: The Gauss genus theory result you mention is for negative discriminants.  Note $h(60)=1$.

Comment: I think you are using the narrow class number, not the full class number. Typically the class number is twice as big as the narrow class number; this is true for 100% of discriminants. I used this to compute the class number: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnopos.php, which gives $h(60) = 2$.

Comment: I am not sure what the correct statement is and I can't seem to find a reference, so I have removed the mention of that. Ultimately though I am interested in the final sum.

Comment: "Typically the class number is twice as big as the narrow class number" It's the other way around, the narrow class number is either equal to or twice as big as the class number. Actually *you* are using the narrow class number, which is equal to the class number of quadratic forms.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that you add the definition of $\epsilon_D$ as well as a reference to the theorem of Siegel in your post.